# Enter an integer that is negative and even or positive and odd

Tags: java

I am creating a program that asks the user for several integers and one of the statements ask the user "Enter an integer that is negative and even or positive and odd". How exactly would I go about setting up such a question? I have this so far. I have no idea how exactly I should do this, as my instructions are pretty confusing. This is what the question is for my problem:

4.
Ask the user for an integer that is either negative and even or positive
and odd. Use an if statement and compound conditional.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseFour   
{
public static void main ( String[] argsv )
{


    int choice;
    int choiceTwo;
    int choiceThree;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println( "Enter a number between 0 and 10" );
        choice = input.nextInt();


            if ( choice > 0 && choice < 10 ) 
            {   System.out.println( "Valid number" );   
            }
            else 
            {   System.out.println( "Invalid number" );
            return;
            }




        System.out.println( "Enter a number divisible by 2 or 3?" );
        choiceTwo = input.nextInt();

            if ( choiceTwo % 2 == 0 && choiceTwo % 3 == 0 )
            {   System.out.println( "Valid number" );
            }
            else    
            {   System.out.println( "Number not divisible by 2 or 3" );
                return;             
            }

        System.out.println( "Enter an integer that is negative and even or positive and odd (Ex. -2 or 7 )" );
        choiceThree = input.nextInt();

            if ( choiceThree  ) 
            { 
            } 
            else 
            { 
            }
```

Comment: Which issue are you facing?

Comment: Nice homework. Any attempts of yours ?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question, this isn't a homework forum, and it tells you "Use an if statement and compound conditional" but you are just ignoring it

Comment: It tells me what to do, but I have NO IDEA how to set up. All I know is if ( choiceThree == 3 || choiceThree == #){, I have no idea what to put for the if statement or the else statement. :x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((choiceThree > 0) && (choiceThree % 2 == 1)) || ((choiceThree < 0) && (choiceThree % 2 == 0))
```

The above is the compound condition you're looking for, which means:

```
(
  (choiceThree > 0)      //positive number / greater than zero
   &&                    // AND
  (choiceThree % 2 == 1) //odd number: (an odd number divided by two has a remainder of 1)
)
||                       // OR
(
 (choiceThree < 0)       //negative number / less than zero
  &&
 (choiceThree % 2 == 0)  //even number (an even number divided by two has a remainder of 0)
)
```

**EDIT:** `%` is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).
The result of `a % b` is the remainder of the integer division `a / b`.

Comment: Valid, but the poster clearly is a beginner, if you expand this to explain what it's doing it might be worth an upvote

Comment: I think I do understand. The > 0 means that it is positive, but what does % 2 == 1 mean?

Comment: @user3304333: I edited the question and tried to answer to your doubts.

Comment: This answer worked for me, and I fully understood it! I now know that int > 0 means it is positive, because it is greater than 0. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use [The modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). An even number is divisible by 2 with no remainder. So:

```
if (choiceThree  < 0) {
    if (choiceThree % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println ("Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("Invalid");
    }
} else {
    if (choiceThree % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println ("Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("Invalid");
    }
}
```

This is a bit cumbersome, of course. A more elegant way to express this boolean logic would be by using the [exclusive or (xor) operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). This operator returns `true` if one and only one of its operands evaluate to `true`:

```
if (choiceThree  > 0 ^ choiceThree % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println ("Valid");
} else {
    System.out.println ("Invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that returns *true* if it's one of those scenarios:

```
public boolean isCorrectInteger(int number){

    if ((number < 0) && (number % 2 == 0)) { //negative and even
        return true;
    } else if((number < 0) && (number % 2 == 1)) { // positive and odd
        return true;
    } else { // other cases
        return false;
    }
}
```

This can be written in a one bigger condition, I've just split it into two for the sake of a simple example.

Also take into consideration that zero is currently assigned neither to positive nor negative - you can change this as you please by using the `<=` or `>=` operators.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake in the second question

```
choiceTwo % 2 == 0 && choiceTwo % 3 == 0
```

you may want to write `||` instead of `&&` becouse you sad devisible to 2 OR 3 ;-)

For your other problem: You have two boolean expressens wich may be true:

Ask the user for an integer that is either negative and even

```
(choiceThree < 0 && choiceThree % 2 == 0)
```

or positive and odd.

```
(choiceThree > 0 && choiceThree   % 2 == 1)
```

Use an if statement and compound conditional.

So just combine these to statements with a logical OR (||)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 System.out.println( "Enter an integer that is negative and even or positive and odd (Ex. -2 or 7 )" );
 choiceThree = input.nextInt();
 if ( (choiceThree>0 && choiceThree%2==1) || (choiceThree<0 && choiceThree%2==0) ) 
 { 
     System.out.println("Correct");
 } 
 else 
 { 
     System.out.printlnt("ERROR");
 }
```